# Perform sum operation in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a checkbox pagination where user select some of the option after user submit he get redirect to the page where he sees what all item he selected and value of the item , I want to get the sum of  the value of item he selected .

```
                    <tbody>
{% for booktest in var1 %}
<tr>
    <td width="100%">{{ booktest }}</td>
    <td>{{ booktest.rate }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</tbody>
```

Above is the HTMl code where i get select item and i want to add all value in {{ booktest.rate }}

```
views.py

def ResultTest(request):
    var = request.POST.get('selectedTests')
    booktests = BookTest.objects.filter(test__in=var.split(','))
```

views.py from where i get selected checkbox data.

Comment: Can you do the sum in the view and then bind the result into a template variable?

Comment: THe sum of what column? `rate`?

Comment: sum of {{ booktest.rate }} as user select multiple item so i get the value of selected items now i want to show the total price of selected item @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: i am not able to get the result of {{ booktest.rate }} in my views @TomDalton

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the sum of the `rate`s with the [**`Sum` aggregate function** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def result_test(request):
    var = request.POST.get('selectedTests')
    booktests = BookTest.objects.filter(test__in=var.split(','))
    total_rate = booktests.aggregate(total=Sum('rate'))['total'] or 0
    # …
```